# Does "that's fair" indicate disagreement in a conversation?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

If I argued with my friends and he texted me, "I got you. Yeah, that's fair." Does he mean he actually disagrees with me?

Comment: It's highly dependent on context and tone of voice.

Comment: It's a text message, so there's no voice. However, the context is we have been arguing on a topic for several times. He replied this message, and stopped discussing the same topic.

Comment: It could mean "OK, you got me on that one."  Or not.  Hard to guess without knowing the sender and the topic.

Comment: From a strictly technical standpoint, "That's fair" means that the statement being evaluated did not somehow stretch the truth or play on an emotional argument, and so was received at "face value".  But there is often some "tone" surrounding such discussions which can change the interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on context it might mean [Agree to Disagree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agree_to_disagree)

Technically and to the specific question, they would still disagree with your point, but tolerate it.

Comment: Although the correspondent might agree to disagree, that might be so even if they said, “You’re right.” Can you provide more justification that “That’s fair” can communicate that sense? To my ear, “That’s fair” sounds like the person has conceded the point.

Comment: @Lawrence I plead "nolo contendere", but in regular English not in legalese.

Comment: I wasn't trying to complicate things; sorry if it appeared that way. Perhaps it would help for you to include an example that brings out the 'agree to disagree' sense.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *that's fair* is ambiguous, when considered outside its context, because, the word *fair* has a number of rather different senses, at least two of which are relevant here. The context will, however, usually disambiguate it.

In one of the relevant senses, *fair* is roughly synonymous with *just*, in the sense of 'in accordance with justice'. If the discussion that preceded the utterance of 'that's fair' was about how to divide, say, the proceeds of some commercial transaction among the people who contributed to it, and after a particular pattern of distribution is proposed, one of the participants says 'that's fair', that expresses an endorsement of that pattern as being in accordance with fairness/justice.

There is, however, also the use of *fair* in various grading scales, where it stands for something that is the next step above failing, but below good, very good, and suchlike. In that sense, saying that something is fair conveys the idea that it only barely satisfies some minimal criteria, and leaves a lot to be desired. Somebody's saying of somebody else's argument 'that's fair' may be based on that use of *fair*, and thus intended to convey the idea that the argument satisfies some minimal criteria of reasonableness (i.e. it's not obviously stupid, easily refutable, etc.), but that it may turn out not to be conclusive, after all. It may thus be a way of acknowledging that the argument has some merit, while still declining to endorse it.

Answer (score 0):

"That's fair" is typically utilized when you bring up a strong point to an argument or conversation. It usually does not mean disagreement.  It's having a strong point to a situation where you and another disagree, at the same time, that strong point may or may not have influence over their initial disagreement with you.

It's fair to say that context and voice are not in text messages- so you can not fully engage what a person's intentions are. Without voice, inflection, tone, you start the question the context of their message.